# How do I clear the JavaScript file cache in Firefox on every visit in a page?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

How can I set the browser to clear the JavaScript file on every visit?

I use Firefox 3.5.7. I am also using the [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) extension for developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way to stop caching of just javascript within Firefox, but you can stop Firefox from using cached files altogether , which will have the same desired effect for developing. Navigate to `about:config` in the address bar and filter to `network.http.use-cache`. Set it to `false` to stop Firefox from using cached files.

You can do the same with the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your programming skills, and why you want to clear the cache, but if you know how to build a Firefox add-on you can try removing the specified JavaScript file from the cache using the interface `nsIDOMOfflineResourceList`. You can get information on the [MDC specific page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDOMOfflineResourceList).

Or the simple solution could be just to use `Ctrl+F5` to reload the page and force the refresh. If it's for websites you develop, you can add a variable at the end of your filename (for example a timestamp or a random number), something like `src="../myFile.js?random=1551533331"`, so the browser will think the file is different and refresh your file everytime (I have never tried it, but it should do the job).